# pandas DataFrame reset_index which can handle duplicate column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, reindex

Is there any equivalent of `pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()` which operates on the columns and can handle the case of duplicate column names? I want it to throw away the column names and return a default numbered index 0,1,2.. for the columns. (Methods like `df.rename` or `df.reindex_axis` do not work when I have duplicate column names.)

Sample input:

```
 pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3), columns = ['A', 'A', 'B'])

     A   A   B
0   0.5 0.3 0.9
1   0.7 0.9 0.3
2   0.9 0.4 0.8
3   0.6 0.2 0.9
4   0.7 0.4 0.6
```

Expected output:

```
     0   1   2
0   0.8 0.1 0.2
1   0.4 0.2 0.4
2   0.3 0.3 0.4
3   0.4 0.1 0.8
4   1.0 0.9 0.9
```

Comment: What is your use case for having duplicate column names? That's generally a very bad idea. You can just strip the column names at the start, save them and add them back at the end if needed.

Comment: @smci I know it is a very bad idea, this is why I want to reset the index :) 
This use case came from concatenating columns from different multiindex dataframes

Comment: Then **you should do a [`join`/`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) on the dataframes**. Not a simple `concat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [set_axis()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) method:

```
In [54]: df
Out[54]:
          A         A         B
0  0.934900  0.817182  0.166270
1  0.064543  0.139431  0.249576
2  0.709349  0.731913  0.965048
3  0.284955  0.479898  0.496652
4  0.520749  0.464256  0.999993

In [55]: df.set_axis(1, range(len(df.columns)))

In [56]: df
Out[56]:
          0         1         2
0  0.934900  0.817182  0.166270
1  0.064543  0.139431  0.249576
2  0.709349  0.731913  0.965048
3  0.284955  0.479898  0.496652
4  0.520749  0.464256  0.999993
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `range` with length of columns by [`shape`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html):

```
df.columns = range(df.shape[1])
print (df)
          0         1         2
0  0.228080  0.884450  0.753401
1  0.176790  0.741979  0.525305
2  0.680255  0.730258  0.449681
3  0.169420  0.660825  0.986554
4  0.302204  0.040413  0.902899
```

Another solution with double transposing by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True`:

```
df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T
print (df)
          0         1         2
0  0.024846  0.688193  0.887926
1  0.284681  0.895319  0.142876
2  0.440834  0.299527  0.762815
3  0.936967  0.928907  0.642960
4  0.801077  0.085773  0.866651
```

Comment: As written in the question, I want to avoid assigning new values to columns.
In particular, I want to do this operation in the context of a dictionary comprehension, where I create the dataframe by concatenating time series and then changing the name of the columns.

Comment: Ok, then use second solution. Unfortunately `reset_index` doesnt work with columns, so need double transposing.